# Return row which have only single value - MySQL

Tags: mysql, unique

[image]

Hello all,

I have multiple rows with same APP_UID value but they might have different IS_DELAYED value ( YES/NO ).

I want if all the rows for a given APP_UID contains IS_DELAYED set to YES then return APP_UID and another derived/new column COMPLETED_ON_TIME set as TRUE else if any one row for a given APP_UID contains IS_DELAYED as NO return APP_UID with COMPLETED_ON_TIME column as FALSE

Comment: This is a perfect example to use a Stored Procedure, while not as recommended as they are in MS SQL, this is a good example for where you would use one in MySQL https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-stored-procedure-tutorial.aspx/

Comment: I agree, but for now i need to run it as raw query :)

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 0):

This works because TRUE > FALSE so the GROUP BY, will give you the right answer

i added another row, so that you can see the better, there are **two** APP_UID

> ```
> CREATE TABLE table1 (
>   `APP_UID` VARCHAR(32),
>   `TAS_UID` VARCHAR(32),
>   `DEL_FINISR_DATE` VARCHAR(19),
>   `DEL_TASX_DUE_DATE` VARCHAR(19),
>   `IS_DELAYED` VARCHAR(3)
> );
>
> INSERT INTO table1
>   (`APP_UID`, `TAS_UID`, `DEL_FINISR_DATE`, `DEL_TASX_DUE_DATE`, `IS_DELAYED`)
> VALUES
>   ('7843186355f2feef3785b24027357425', '2187105555f2d16842de705093498513', '2020-08-09    19:49:15', '2020-08-07  12:41:00', 'YES'),
>   ('7843186355f2feef3785b24027357425', '4687454845f2d16841e8b94080324338', '2020-08-09    12:42:05', '2020-08-10  17:00:00', 'NO'),
>   ('7843186355f2feef3785b24027357425', '5835200885f2d1683e38d34012502360', '2020-08-09    19:49:54', '2020-08-10  17:00:00', 'NO'),
>   ('7843186355f2feef3785k24027357425', '5835200885f2d1683e38d34012502360', '2020-08-09    19:49:54', '2020-08-10  17:00:00', 'NO');
> ```

> ```
> SELECT `APP_UID`, MAX(CASE WHEN `IS_DELAYED` = 'YES' THEN 'TRUE' 
> WHEN `IS_DELAYED` = 'NO' THEN 'FALSE'
> END) COMPLETED_ON_TIME
> FROM table1
> GROUP BY `APP_UID`
> ```
>
> ```
> APP_UID                          | COMPLETED_ON_TIME
> :------------------------------- | :----------------
> 7843186355f2feef3785b24027357425 | TRUE             
> 7843186355f2feef3785k24027357425 | FALSE
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=abd353fd72fafc3c9b2bef560feca8ea)*

Comment: Thanks @nbk but you see since for the same APP_UID i have both values YES and NO in IS_DELAYED column so the result should be a single row
7843186355f2feef3785b24027357425 : FALSE

If in case i had onyl YES in IS_DELAYED for same APP_UID then i would have :
7843186355f2feef3785k24027357425 : TRUE

Comment: The code groups by the APP-uid, so you get only one result , if there is yes and no it returns True for every uid, in the example has **two unique app_uid**  Your image is very bad, so use text to have a better example.

Answer (score 0):

The next approach can be used in this case:

```
SELECT 
    `APP_UID`, 
    IF (
        GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT `IS_DELAYED` ORDER BY `IS_DELAYED`) = 'YES', -- 'YES' , 'NO' or 'NO,YES' result possible
        'TRUE', 
        'FALSE'
    ) AS `COMPLETED_ON_TIME` 
FROM `TBL`
GROUP BY `APP_UID`;
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=5c23907fcd431ea6cff6106fa87da822)